# Trouble with nested classes. "error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token"

Tags: c++, class, nested-class

I'm having trouble declaring a nested class. My question is how do I properly declare a nested class and call its members. I've tried googling it and tried different approaches, but I can't seem to make it work. Right now I get "error: expected unqualified-id before '{'  token" on the line LongInt::Digit{

This is what I'm trying:

**Header File**

```
class LongInt {

 public:
    class Digit{
        public:
        int data;
        Digit(int d);
    };

    // Constructor
    LongInt();
};
```

**Cpp File**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "LongInt.h"
using namespace std;

LongInt::Digit{
    Digit next;
    Digit prev;

    LongInt::Digit::Digit (int d) { 
         data = d;
         next = NULL;
         prev = NULL;
    }
}

LongInt::Digit front;
LongInt::Digit back;
LongInt::Digit curr;

LongInt::LongInt() {
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: looks like you forgot closing `LongInt` class

Comment: Sorry it was there in my code. I forgot to copy it into the question.

Comment: There's still a semicolon missing `};`

Comment: That was there too. Sorry, I can't copy right. Also the include guards and everything else was there too.

Comment: Your first code block in the `.cpp` file is syntactically wrong. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
LongInt::Digit{
    Digit next;
    Digit prev;

    LongInt::Digit::Digit (int d) { 
        data = d;
        next = NULL;
        prev = NULL;
    }
};
```

Looks like you're doing a *'partial redeclaration'* of the `Digit` class, which is not possible.

You should fully declare your nested class in the header

```
class LongInt {

 public:
    class Digit{
        public:
        int data;
        Digit(int d);
        Digit* next;
        Digit* prev;
    };

    // Constructor
    LongInt();
};
```

And your constructor simply as

```
LongInt::Digit::Digit (int d) : data(d), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {
}
```

Comment: +1 for the initialization list. I skipped it in my answer to try to keep as much of his code as I could.

Answer (score 1):

Members for the inner class should be declared in the inner class.
Also, I think there are a couple of places where you meant to have pointers, but you had objects (You usually want to assign `NULL` to pointers).

Also, you only declared a `Digit` constructor which takes an `int`, and no constructor which takes no arguments, so you cannot declare a `Digit` without an argument.

Finally, you really should not be doing the three assignments inside `LongInt::LongInt()`, because those variables are not pointers.

Here is the `.h` file:

```
class LongInt {

 public:
    class Digit{
        public:
            Digit*  next;
            Digit*  prev;
            int data;
            Digit(int d);
    };

    // Constructor
    LongInt();
};
```

Here is the `.cc` file:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "LongInt.h"
using namespace std;

LongInt::Digit::Digit (int d) { 
     data = d;
     next = NULL;
     prev = NULL;
}

LongInt::Digit front(1);
LongInt::Digit back(1);
LongInt::Digit curr(1);

LongInt::LongInt() {
    // front = NULL;
    // back = NULL;
    // curr = NULL;
}
```